# cannot do multiple query indexed firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so i tried to get data from firebase using this function

```
getData(){
        const startDate = this.$store.state.inputFilter.rangeDate.start
        const endDate = this.$store.state.inputFilter.rangeDate.end
        db.collection(this.inputType)
        .where('idAlat', '==',this.equipment)
        .where('tanggal', '>=', startDate).where('tanggal', '<=', endDate)
        .where('project', '==', this.project)
        .get().then(docs => {
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data().tanggal.toDate(), doc.data().idAlat)
            })
        })
    }
```

but then every time i try to run the fucntion, it shows error like this in console:
[image: error in console]

but then i follow the link and do the instruction to create composite index in firebase like this:
[image: firestore index setting]

Is there something wrong i did? Thanks!

PS: word 'tanggal' means 'date' in english

Comment: did u click add index?

Comment: If i click 'add index' it will just add another index.

Comment: Adding the index prescribed by the error message should prevent that error message from happening again.  Are you saying that you added the index and the error is still happening?